# Mapping keys to methods in Java

Tags: java

I know how to use `HashMaps` and stuff to map keys to values. I was just wondering if you could map keys to methods as well.

For example, a program asks the user for input. Then it calls a method that has its name as the input entered. ie: if the input is `"cat"`, method `cat()` is invoked.

Obviously one can use if statements, but is there an easier way?

Comment: Another thing: when I type Java code, how do I make it appear in a code format?

Comment: @FlameKnight123 How do you make it appear in a code format? Type it in an IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans. Or did you mean when asking a question? In that case, either surround the code with ` (this will put it on **one** line) or put four spaces before the code (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more details)

Answer (score 2):

Fetch the method and invoke it.

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method = class_obj.getClass().getMethod("functionName"); // add params if any
method.invoke(); // add params if any
```

This would be equivalent to calling the function

```
functionName(void);
```

This is for the case when you have to pass no parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Map`s of pretty much anything to anything. Your scenario is certainly an unorthodox application though.

But if you insist, you can just do this:

```
Map<String, Method> map = new HashMap<>(); //Java 7
Method[] methods = ClassToMap.class.getDeclaredMethods() //First link 
for(Method m : methods) {
  map.put(m.getName(), m);  //Second link
}
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)

And now you have a `Map` of names of methods to methods you can then call--although you need to use the `Method` API to call them.

Comment: Forgot the type declaration for `m`. You couldn't have added that? Really? Haha

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String name = args[0];
    Method method = Test.class.getDeclaredMethod(name, new Class[]{});
    method.invoke(null, new Object[]{});
  }

  public static void method1() {
    System.out.println("in method1()");
  }

  public static void method2() {
    System.out.println("in method2()");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to invoke specific method (which is not an object-oriented approach), you should create an interface with one method (or use `Runnable`) and implement each invokable method in a separate class. Then put instance of these classes into map and invoke implemented method on the matching object:

```
Map<String, Runnable> myMap = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
// fill myMap with your objects
String input = ...; // get user input

if (myMap.containsKey(input)) {
    myMap.get(input).run();
}
```

Also, see [strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [Java Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html). Here is a basic example, although in practice you should make your exception catching logic more advanced:

```
public class JavaDynamicMethodsExample {

    public void cat() {
        System.out.println("Meow!");
    }
    
    public void dog() {
        System.out.println("Bark!");
    }
    
    public void bird() {
        System.out.println("Chirp!");
    }
    
    public void callMethod(String methodName) {
        try {
            Method method = this.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
            method.invoke(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not call method with name: " + methodName);
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
    
        JavaDynamicMethodsExample example = new JavaDynamicMethodsExample();
    
        String [] methods = {"cat", "dog", "hamster", "bird"};
    
        for(String methodName : methods) {
            example.callMethod(methodName);
        }
    
    }
}
```

This will output:

> Meow!
>
> Bark!
>
> Could not call method with name: hamster
>
> Chirp!

Answer (score -1):

You could do string to [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html).

For instance in your case, you can do something like:

```
String k = "cat"

String caller(String key)
{
    String ret = null;
    if (key.equals(k)) 
    {
    ret = cat();
    }
    return ret;
}

String cat() {}
```

So every time you pass an user's input to `caller()` function, method `cat()` is invoked.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you mean.

Comment: OP has explicitly said he want to avoid using bunch of `if`s to switch between methods to call.